# Ajax get response limit size?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, web, xmlhttprequest

I'm using AJAX for getting image(.tif) from the node.js server
it's working OK for the image size up to 232MB but when I try to GET image size of 262MB it' cannot and respose Not Found...
I'don't understand why?
The response of GET has limit size?

Thank you for your answer

Comment: why are you loading an image with Ajax?

Comment: @epascarello because I want the response as arraybuffer to process something. Do you have any idea?